# Selecting rows with repeating values in one column

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server 2008 R2 using this table:

```
CREATE TABLE mytest(
     id [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
     code [bigint] NULL,
     sequence_number [int] NULL
);
```

This query:

```
SELECT id, code, sequence_number
  FROM mytable
```

returns this data:

```
 id     code    sequence_number
  1      381        0
  2      381        1
  3      382        0
  4      382        1
  5      383        0
  6      383        1
  7      383        1
  8      384        0
  9      384        1
  10     385        0
  11     385        1
  12     385        2
  13     386        0
  14     386        1
  15     386        1
  16     386        2
  17     387        0
  18     387        1
  19     387        1
  20     387        2
  21     387        3
  22     387        3
  23     388        0
  24     388        1
  25     388        1
  26     388        2
  27     388        2
  28     389        0
  29     389        1
```

How do I `SELECT` just these rows:

```
7   383 1
15  386 1
19  387 1
22  387 3
25  388 1
27  388 2
```

These are the the `MAX(id)` rows where there is more than one record with the same sequence_number. I want all the highest ids for each unique combination of code and sequence_number.

So, in effect I want to select just the "duplicate" sequence_number records.

How do I do this?

Comment: have you tried my ans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
SELECT 
    MAX(t1.Id) as ID, 
    t1.code, 
    t1.sequence_number
FROM mytest t1
INNER JOIN mytest t2
ON t1.id <> t2.id
AND t1.code = t2.code
AND t1.sequence_number = t2.sequence_number
GROUP BY t1.code, 
    t1.sequence_number
    ORDER BY ID
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :-

```
 Select ID,code,sequence_number from
 (
  Select ID,
         code,
         [rn] = row_number() over (partition by code,sequence_number order by id),
         sequence_number
  from yourTable
 )s
 where rn > 1
```

Demo in [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4793c/8)

Answer (score 1):

`select code,MAX(sequence_number) from mytest
group by code`